# Line two divs side by side with CSS and React

Tags: css, reactjs

As the image shows, I have two components that I want to be side by side and lined up: [image: Dashboard]

I am using React and the component with `Negotiation`, `frontend`, and `food` has elements passed from another component.

How do I style this so each element (`Negotiation`, `Frontend` and `food`) are separated from each other but still in the same column with news lined up next to it?

My JavaScript:

```
class Course extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="coursecontent">
          <h3>{this.props.coursename}</h3>
          <h4> {this.props.status} {this.props.progress}</h4>
        </div>
        <button className="coursecontent">Start exercise</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Welcomebox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Welcome Naomi</h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Welcomebox />, document.getElementById('welcomebox'));

class Coursebox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="box-field">
        <Course coursename="Negotiation" progress= "20%" status="Progress"/>
        <Course coursename="Frontend" progress="56%" status="Progress"/>
        <Course coursename="Food" status="Progress" progress="43%"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Newsbox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="box-field" className="newsbox">
        <h3>News</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Dashboardbox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dashboardbox">
        <Coursebox />
        <Newsbox />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Dashboardbox />, document.getElementById('dashboardbox'));
```

My CSS:

```
.box-field,
.newsbox {
  width: 45%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-family: arial;
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 80%;
  padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

So basically, in between each `Course` element I would want space (preferably set with `Margin`), and I want the `Newsbox` component to line up with the `Coursebox` component.

Comment: can you wrap your `Newsbox` component and `Coursebox` component in one `div` ?

Comment: Did you try using FlexBox? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I have wrapped it in one div. In react you have to do that to pass more than one element to another component. @AatifBandey

Comment: @Zeus77 never used flexbox before but I heard that might make it easier. I'll possibly look into it

Comment: did my solution help you ? @Naomi

Comment: @AatifBandey exactly what I was looking for. I'll accept it as an answer as soon as I'm allowed to. Cheers!

Comment: @Naomi thanks. Cheers

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Solution to bring new `Newsbox` component next to `Coursebox`

```
import Coursebox from './Coursebox';
import Newsbox  from './Newsbox'
 class ContainerRow extends React.Component {
 render(){
    return (
        <div className='rowC'>
            <Coursebox />
            <Newsbox />
        </div>
    );
    }
 }
```

CSS

```
.rowC{display:flex; flex-direction:row;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the CSS. (y)

Comment: Yep - that works!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
const ParentDiv = styled.div`
  & {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;

const ChildDiv = styled.div`
  & {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want style difference between Course components you can pass a className using props when you call the component. Or if you are using bootstrap you can just pass "well" or "panel" class.

For example;

```
class Course extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">{this.props.coursename}</div>
         <div class="panel-body">
          <h4> {this.props.status} {this.props.progress}</h4>
            <button className="coursecontent">Start exercise</button>
         </div>
       </div> 
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels