# Display two div's in line with React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to display the content of two `div` in a single row, so I wrapped them with another `div` and set its `display` attribute to `flex`. Both divs are displayed in the same row, but one over the other, instead of adjacent.

[image]

I tried [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702130/line-two-divs-side-by-side-with-css-and-react), but it didn't work.

This is the code of my component:

```
            <TableFooter>
                <TableRow>
                  <div className="crud-footer">
                    <div className="col-6">
                      <TablePagination
                        count={data.length}
                        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                        page={page}
                        onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
                        onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-6 crud-controls">
                      <Fab className="jr-fab-btn bg-blue text-white">
                        <i className="zmdi zmdi-plus zmdi-hc-fw"/>
                      </Fab>
                      <Fab className="jr-fab-btn bg-yellow text-white">
                        <i className="zmdi zmdi-edit zmdi-hc-fw"/>
                      </Fab>
                      <Fab className="jr-fab-btn bg-red text-white">
                        <i className="zmdi zmdi-delete zmdi-hc-fw"/>
                      </Fab>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </TableRow>
              </TableFooter>
```

And this is the `css` for the divs:

```
.crud-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.crud-controls {
  display: flex;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the css framework you use - if any, or seeing more css, it is difficult to determine the issue.

A quick look at the classes and seems you may be missing a parent `row` class on the div crud-footer for the two child `col-6` columns. maybe just overlooked adding `<div className="crud-footer row">` from you css framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `justify-content` on your container. Depending on what kind of layout you're looking for set it to `flex-start` or `space-between`.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp

Also make sure you container has enough room to fit both. (e.g. `width: 100%`)