# How to display two icons side by side in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I'm developing an app for a school project and i've been trying to show two icons side by side for a screen (i've been using React for 5 months but i'm still a noob at it)

But they display one over the other, i even tried using Bootstrap columns to make it show them the way i want but i just couldn't do it

Here's the code

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
// import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CheckCircle from '@mui/icons-material/CheckCircle'
import styles from '../../App';
import { GiBroom } from 'react-icons/gi';
import { borderRadius } from "@mui/system";
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

export default function LimpiarCurso(){
    return (
        <Container style={styles.container}>
      <Row>
      <Col><CheckCircle sx={{ fontSize: 200, color: 'white', backgroundColor:'green', display:'inline-block'}} style={{float: 'right'}}/></Col>
      <Col><GiBroom size={200} style={{float: 'right', display: 'inline-block'}}/></Col>
      </Row>
      </Container> 
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line two divs side by side with CSS and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702130/line-two-divs-side-by-side-with-css-and-react)

Answer (score 0):

First of all greetings .These are all basic mistakes that were made by freshers .Don't worry. Try putting those Icons inside a **{View}** tag. And give some styles for View as below . This works for me .

```js
 import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View ,TouchableOpacity,ScrollView} from 'react-native'
import React from 'react';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons,Ionicons,FontAwesome5 } from '@expo/vector-icons';

 <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-evenly'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons 
                                name='message-alert'
                                size={50}
                                color={'#BACAFF'}
                    />
                    <Text>New Complaint</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons 
                                name='message-alert'
                                size={50}
                                color={'#BACAFF'}
                    />
                   <Text>Track a Complaint</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
 
 
 
 
 The styles for button is 
 
    button:{
        padding:20,
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        elevation:10,
        shadowColor:'#000',
        borderRadius:10,
        alignContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
    },
```

[image: The Output will be like this]